# Union[Decimal, int] incompatible with Decimal?

Tags: python-3.5, mypy

Considering the following program:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import Union

def foo(bar: Union[Decimal, int]):
    print(Decimal(1) + bar)
    print(bar + Decimal(1))
```

Why does `mypy` complain in the second print()?

```
$ mypy foo.py
foo.py: note: In function "foo":
foo.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("Union[Decimal, int]" and "Decimal")
```

I'm using mypy 0.3.1 on Python 3.5.1, Ubuntu 16.04.

**EDIT**: This seems to be a [bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1442).

Comment: Perhaps it's not dealing correctly with the possibility of `__radd__` being used.

Comment: A bug you mean? The stub for decimal types is here: https://github.com/python/mypy/commit/323928a719c885f389ce8ae0c6f0df9f3e8c6e8d

Comment: Possibly, it's certainly not the behaviour I'd expect. Have you tried raising it as an issue?

Comment: OK, I'll do it, thanks!